# Angular JS - Can I display a module constant in HTML?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-module

I have a module with a constant like this:

```
angular.module('SampleMod',[])
.constant("VERSION", "2.1");
```

I want to show the constant value in HTML with something like this:

```
<p>{{VERSION}}</p>
```

Is it possible (without passing by the controller)?

Comment: The whole idea of angular is to inject dependencies. You could use `$rootScope` to set and get your constant but I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: Another solution would be to create a service which uses `$http.get()` to grab information from a JSON file. Then you could update the file without having to change any code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$rootScope` for this, but you would have to assign the value to `$rootScope` at some point. You could also use a directive that does essentially the same thing.

```js
angular.module('SampleMod',[])
.constant("VERSION", "2.1")
.run(function ($rootScope, VERSION) {
  $rootScope.VERSION = VERSION;
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app=SampleMod>
<p>{{VERSION}}</p>
```

Comment: I don't see any directive here. Do you mean the run block?

Comment: Nice, but it's not very different from do it in the controller... Maybe it's impossible do it without any assignement.