# Using constant inside HTML file

Tags: angularjs

I have following constants.js code:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp');

app.constant('globalConstant', {
    TYPE: {
        0: 'Good',
        1: 'Bad'
    }
});
```

My list.js:

```
app.controller('myCtrl', 
['$scope', '$rootScope', 'globalConstant', 
function ($scope, $rootScope, globalConstant) {
    $scope.type = globalConstant.TYPE;
}]);
```

My list.jade:

```
div {{type[{{data.type}}]}} //data.type will be either 0 or 1
```

However it throws me error:

> Syntax Error: Token '{' invalid key at column 16 of the expression
>   [type[{{data.type] starting at
>   [{data.type].

What is the correct way to use the constant inside my HTML file?

Comment: See the below Link: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27678465/angular-js-can-i-display-a-module-constant-in-html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27678465/angular-js-can-i-display-a-module-constant-in-html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use simply `{{type[data.type]}}`

Everything between `{{}}` is interpreted as JavaScript so you don't need an extra pair of those.